# How to open and edit .wlmp video

Tags: video, video-conversion, video-editing, windows-movie-maker, windows-live-movie-maker

I have made a video using `Window Movie Maker`. I have formatted my computer and lost the program installation files. Now I found that Microsoft stopped supporting `movie maker` and it is no longer available.

I have to edit the video that is saved as `.wlmp`. Please help me. It is an important file and I do not have time or resources to redo it.

EDIT: I tried to install Windows essentials 2012. I got this error message.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MS *Movie Maker*, though no longer actively supported, is available as part of the *Windows Live Essentials 2012* package, and *Movie Maker* runs under Windows 10 as well as older versions. It's available from [CNET](https://download.cnet.com/Windows-Live-Essentials-2012/3000-20418_4-10805747.html), [The Wayback Machine](http://web.archive.org/web/20170112124505/http:/wl.dlservice.microsoft.com/download/C/1/B/C1BA42D6-6A50-4A4A-90E5-FA9347E9360C/en/wlsetup-all.exe), etc.

When installing, select only *Movie Maker* and *Photo Gallery* -- I know of no way to install one without the other.

*Caveat*, unless one preserves them through the [Registry](https://winaero.com/blog/prevent-windows-10-from-resetting-your-default-apps/), this will likely mess up some file associations, so that next time a .PNG, .JPEG etc. file is double-clicked, the default program will need to be specified again.

Comment: installation failed with me. Could you look at the edited post? I am using Win. 10 x64.

Comment: It looks like the error, "PhotoGalleryLang", points to a language pack isue, but see https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windowslive/forum/gallery-wlinstall/trying-to-updating-windows-essentials-get-error/0816388a-cbfd-492b-a590-e0c6b8a0799f and Google the error.